# Open FTP in iFrame

Tags: php, html, iframe

I want open an FTP connection inside an iFrame, but the problem is that if the FTP connection requires a username, the popup to put the username and password is not opened, it only runs if the FTP connection requires no username.

```
<iframe src="ftp://server.com/"></iframe>
```

What Can I do?

Answer (score 3):

```
<iframe src="ftp://user:password@server.com/"></iframe>
```

If that doesn't work, it's not possible at all.

Comment: sorry but I don't want put the user and passord in src, there are differents users...

Comment: You wouldn't hard-code them into the page; you'd query the user for their username and password, then use those when generating the URL for the iframe. The user will be able to see their own username and password in the code for the page and in their browser history, which is insecure, but FTP isn't particularly secure in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

What you might have to do is implement your own display of the contents of the FTP location with PHP.

You can create a connection to an FTP server and manipulate the files there with PHP quite simply.
[Taken from the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php)

```
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

// output $contents
var_dump($contents);
```

> The above example will output something similar to:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "public_html"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "public_ftp"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "www"
```

From this point [all the FTP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php) are available and at your disposal.

You can use them to render an HTML representation of the files and folders listed on the FTP server and possibly also let the users perform actions on them such as

- Renaming
- Deletion
- Display contents
- etc...